How to Send SOAP Requests in SAP CAP: S/4HANA Cloud WSDLs vs. External SOAP Services
I am working on a project using the SAP Cloud Application Programming (CAP) model and I need to integrate SOAP-based services. I understand that there are two main ways to send SOAP requests in SAP CAP:
Using SOAP WSDLs from S/4HANA Cloud: I know that S/4HANA Cloud provides SOAP WSDLs for various services, but I need more details on how to set up and consume these services within a CAP project. What are the best practices for integrating these WSDLs? Are there any specific configurations or libraries I should be aware of?
Consuming External SOAP Services: Apart from S/4HANA Cloud, I also need to consume external SOAP services. What are the key differences and additional considerations when integrating external SOAP services into a CAP project? Are there any particular challenges or recommended tools for this?
I am looking for detailed guidance, including code snippets, configuration steps, and any potential pitfalls to avoid. Any examples or documentation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help in advance!
